# rbind and cbind lists together

Tags: r, lapply, rbind, cbind

I have the code below in which I rbind the lists SampleDf and sampleDF2 together, and then cbind two character vectors on to it.  What I would like to do is create a function where I could pass it another sampleDF3, Recipe3, and list of ingredients and have them similarly rbind and cbind together.  Is there a simple way to do this with like lapply or do.call?  My end goal is to be able to pass the function a list of sampleDF, Recipe, and ingredients and have them all rbind and cbind together similar to the example below.

```
Code:
try1<-cbind(cbind(RecipeName<-c("Recipe1","Recipe2"),ingredients<-c("","Beans"))
          ,rbind(
                  SampleDf
                 ,sampleDf2

                  )
             )


Data:

dput(SampleDf)
structure(c(45.8490717149901, 75.6532220962743, 49.4757541141121, 
21.7923657299986, 153.255016847245), .Dim = c(1L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(
    "Test set", c("ME", "RMSE", "MAE", "MPE", "MAPE")))

dput(sampleDf2)
structure(c(-1.39930351254246, 65.1992541962796, 46.5664097914753, 
-364.369685854671, 412.539393211685), .Dim = c(1L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(
    "Test set", c("ME", "RMSE", "MAE", "MPE", "MAPE")))

dput(sampleDf3)
structure(c(0, 65.1992541962796, 1, 
-364.369685854671, 10), .Dim = c(1L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(
    "Test set", c("ME", "RMSE", "MAE", "MPE", "MAPE")))
```

Comment: If you look at the output from `try1` it is all character columns.  I guess that is not what you wanted, right?.   place the `sample` datasets in a `list`, convert to `data.frame` and then use the `do.call(rbind` i.e. `res <- do.call(rbind, lapply(mget(ls(pattern="(?i)SampleDf\\d*")), as.data.frame))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
require(dplyr)
bind_all <- function(rows, cols){
  rows <- lapply(rows, as.data.frame)
  cols <- vapply(cols, as.data.frame, list(1))
  bind_cols(bind_rows(rows), cols)
}

bind_all(list(SampleDf, sampleDf2), 
         list(RecipeName=c("Recipe1","Recipe2"),ingredients=c("","Beans")))
```

Which gives you:

```
         ME     RMSE      MAE        MPE     MAPE RecipeName ingredients
1 45.849072 75.65322 49.47575   21.79237 153.2550    Recipe1            
2 -1.399304 65.19925 46.56641 -364.36969 412.5394    Recipe2       Beans
```